# Function which takes a column values and convert it into a comma separated values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want an SQL function which takes a result of a select statement as parameter and return a string of comma separated values for the result. If there is a `NULL` value then it should leave a space and continue with the result.

I tried using the `COALESCE()` expression, but this takes out the `NULL` values and returns only valid values.

```
declare @str varchar(MAX)

SELECT @str= coalesce(@str + ',', '')+ a.D8_BOOK_YEAR_END 
FROM (select D8_BOOK_YEAR_END from CUST_PRODUCT_ACCOUNTS 
WHERE CUST_PRODUCT_ID=1) a

print @str
```

For example: In the image, I need to pass the column `NAME` into the function and it should return me the values as `Mango, ,Apple,Grape`.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want an **SQL function** which takes a **result of a select statement as parameter** and **return a string of comma separated values** for the result. **If there is a null value then it should leave a space** and continue with the result.

You can do that as

```
--Create a table (just for test)
CREATE TABLE T(
  Str VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('One'),
(NULL),
('Two'),
('Three');

-- Create a type
CREATE TYPE MyData AS TABLE (Str NVARCHAR(300));

-- Create the function
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunc(
  @Data MyData READONLY
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(300)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result NVARCHAR(300) = N'';
  SELECT @Result = STUFF(
                         ( 
                          SELECT ',' + ISNULL(Str, '') --Or ' ' as you like
                          FROM @Data 
                          FOR XML PATH('')
                         ), 1, 1, ''
                        ); 
  RETURN (@Result);
END

-- Finally, use it
DECLARE @Test MyData;

INSERT INTO @Test SELECT * FROM T;

SELECT dbo.MyFunc(@Test);
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------------+
| (No column name) |
+------------------+
| One,,Two,Three   |
+------------------+
```

And **[`here is a live demo`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d998b4364e77c6a0ca8da797f5e105c8)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL(field,' ')` somewhere to avoid the `NULL` value behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (
    ID INT 
    ,Info VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (1,'mango')

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (1,'apple')

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (1,null)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (1,'grape')

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (2,'mango1')

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (2,null)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (2,null)

INSERT INTO @TABLE
VALUES (2,'grape1')


SELECT ID
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ',' + isnull(info, '')
            FROM @TABLE T1
            WHERE T1.id = T2.ID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
FROM @TABLE T2
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL Concatenation using XML PATH()](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) method as illustrated with following sample query

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ',' + [user]
    FROM dbo.UserCategoryValues
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) As concatenated_string
```

This will take care of NULL values. Those NULLs will not be concatenated in to the list

But you can not wrap this code into a function as dynamic SQL that will take the field name and table name and build a SQL statement dynamically. SQL engine will throw an exception in that case